# notify onSwiped method that list is sorted in mainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I am using recyclerView to show list of apps installed in device, I implement onSwipe method to perform uninstall ....along with sorting feature such as name, size etc..

Now when I sort list according to name onswipe viewholder ...doesn't refresh

> Suppose in a list ...at index[1]...gallery app is there,  after
> sorting this goes to index[10] now the problem is onSwipe method think
> gallery is at index[1], but actually it is displayed on index[10] in
> recyclerView ..

**Problem occur here is** when I swipe at index[1] it execute uninstall dialog of gallery but it is displayed at [10]

---

*How to notify onSwiped method that list is sorted and every item change its index*

---

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var adapter: Adapter  // create adapter instance
lateinit var applicationList:MutableList<AppData>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    applicationList = getApps(installedApps()) // initialize applicationList variable
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = Adapter(applicationList) // initialize adapter variable
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter // pass adapter to recyclerView

   sortList()

          // I create sepearate abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback and call here

    val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback(this) {
        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            currentItem = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val packageName =
                applicationList[currentItem].packageName // get packageName from position
            val appCategory = applicationList[currentItem].category

                uninstall() // call uninstall function
        }
        
    }
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView) // attach onSwipe to recyclerView

}

fun uninstall(){
    // perform uninstall 
}

private fun installedApps(): MutableList<ResolveInfo> {
  // get installed apps
}

fun sortList() { 
    Sort_List.setOnClickListener {
        val popUp = PopupMenu(this, Sort_List)
        popUp.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_menu, popUp.menu)

        popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener { myItem ->
            when (myItem.itemId) {
                R.id.Name_ASC -> {
                    
                    val sortedList =  applicationList.sortedBy { it.name }
                    adapter.update(sortedList)
                }
                R.id.Name_DES -> {
                    val sortedList =  applicationList.sortedByDescending { it.name }
                    adapter.update(sortedList)
                }
              }
            true
        }
        popUp.show()
    }
}


private fun getApps(List: MutableList<ResolveInfo>): MutableList<AppData> {

    // fetch all apps and return list
}
```

SwipeToDeleteCallback.kt

```
abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback(context: Context) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

private val deleteIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_delete_white)
private val intrinsicWidth = deleteIcon?.intrinsicWidth
private val intrinsicHeight = deleteIcon?.intrinsicHeight
private val background = ColorDrawable()
private val backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#f44336")
private val clearPaint = Paint().apply { xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR) }


override fun getMovementFlags(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Int {
    return super.getMovementFlags(recyclerView, viewHolder)
}

override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onChildDraw(
    c: Canvas,
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    dX: Float,
    dY: Float,
    actionState: Int,
    isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
) {
    val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
    val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
    val isCanceled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

    if (isCanceled){
        clearCanvas(c,itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    }

    // Draw the red delete button
   
    //Calculate position of delete icon
   
    // Draw the delete icon
    
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
}

private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas?, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
    c?.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, clearPaint)
}
```

Adapter.kt

```
class Adapter(private var listOfApps: MutableList<AppData>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(appView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(appView) {

    // call elements from list_apps.xml
    val icon: ImageView = appView.App_icon
    val name: TextView = appView.App_name
    val size: TextView = appView.App_size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.list_apps, parent, false
    )
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = listOfApps.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val currentItem = listOfApps[position]
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(currentItem.icon) 
    holder.name.text = currentItem.name
    holder.size.text = currentItem.size
    
}
fun update(newList: MutableList<AppData>){
    listOfApps = newList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one problem i see in your code:
you are using **applicationList** to get swiped item inside **onSwiped**
but after sorting you are putting another list to adapter.
there are two ways to fix this

1. get swiped item from adaptor
2. or use **sortBy**() instead of **sortedBy**() for sorting list

MODIFY SNIPPET TO

```
popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener { myItem ->
        when (myItem.itemId) {
            R.id.Name_ASC -> {
                
                applicationList.sortBy{ it.name }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            R.id.Name_DES -> {
                applicationList.sortByDescending{ it.name }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
          }
        true
    }
```

Comment: after getting swiped item then,,,,,what to do in onSwiped ??

Comment: moreover ......sortBy return Unit ....I need List...that is obtained with sortedBy

Comment: you don't need list if you are using sortBy. You just notify adapter notifyDataSetChanged, becasue  applicationList itself sorted

Comment: Can you please share coding sample of that

Comment: UPDATED MY ANSWER JUST USE THIS CODE. I THINK AFTER THIS EVERYTHING WILL WORK FINE